# probability calculation for bayesian network

Tags: probability, statistics, bayesian-network

I am studying Bayesian belief networks and in that I am struggling to understand how probabilities are calculated. 
I found this article [here](http://artint.info/html/ArtInt_148.html)

and the network is this:
  [image]

The associated probabilities are:
[image]

I don't understand how the probability
P(Tampering=true|Report=T) is calculated.

How I did it was

> P(Alarm=T|Tampering=T,Fire=T)*P(Leaving=T|Alarm=T)*P(Report=T|Leaving=T)*P(Tampering=T)+
>   P(Alarm=T|Tampering=T,Fire=F)*P(Leaving=T|Alarm=T)*P(Report=T|Leaving=T)*P(Tampering=T)+
>   P(Alarm=F|Tampering=T,Fire=T)*P(Leaving=T|Alarm=F)*P(Report=T|Leaving=T)*P(Tampering=T)+
>   P(Alarm=F|Tampering=T,Fire=F)*P(Leaving=T|Alarm=F)*P(Report=T|Leaving=T)*P(Tampering=T)+
>   P(Alarm=T|Tampering=T,Fire=T)*P(Leaving=F|Alarm=T)*P(Report=T|Leaving=F)*P(Tampering=T)+
>    P(Alarm=T|Tampering=T,Fire=F)*P(Leaving=F|Alarm=T)*P(Report=T|Leaving=F)*P(Tampering=T)+
>   P(Alarm=F|Tampering=T,Fire=T)*P(Leaving=F|Alarm=F)*P(Report=T|Leaving=F)*P(Tampering=T)+
>   P(Alarm=F|Tampering=T,Fire=F)*P(Leaving=F|Alarm=F)*P(Report=T|Leaving=F)*P(Tampering=T)
>   which gives me a value= 0.017989

But the given answer for `P(tampering=T|report=T) = 0.399`

How do I calculate this probability

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the calculation should be:

\begin{align}
P(T\mid R) &= \dfrac{P(R,T)}{P(R)} = \dfrac{P(R,T)}{P(R,T)+P(R,\neg T)} \\
& \\
P(R,T) &= \sum_{L,A,F\in\{True,False\}} P(R,T,A,F) \\
&= \sum_{L,A,F\in\{True,False\}} P(R\mid L)\;P(L\mid A)\;P(L\mid T,F)\;P(T)\;P(F) \\
& \\
&=   (0.75)(0.88)(0.5)(0.02)(0.01) & \qquad [L,A,F] \\
&= + (0.75)(0.88)(0.85)(0.02)(0.99) & \qquad [L,A,\neg F] \\
&= + (0.75)(0.001)(0.5)(0.02)(0.01) & \qquad [L,\neg A,F] \\
&= + (0.75)(0.001)(0.15)(0.02)(0.99) & \qquad [L,\neg A,\neg F] \\
&= + (0.01)(0.12)(0.5)(0.02)(0.01) & \qquad [\neg L,A,F] \\
&= + (0.01)(0.12)(0.85)(0.02)(0.99) & \qquad [\neg L,A,\neg F] \\
&= + (0.01)(0.999)(0.5)(0.02)(0.01) & \qquad [\neg L,\neg A,F] \\
&= + (0.01)(0.999)(0.15)(0.02)(0.99) & \qquad [\neg L,\neg A,\neg F] \\
& \\
&= 0.011227. \\
& \\
P(R,\neg T) &= \sum_{L,A,F\in\{True,False\}} P(R,\neg T,A,F) \\
&= \sum_{L,A,F\in\{True,False\}} P(R\mid L)\;P(L\mid A)\;P(L\mid \neg T,F)\;P(\neg T)\;P(F) \\
& \\
&=   (0.75)(0.88)(0.99)(0.98)(0.01) & \qquad [L,A,F] \\
&= + (0.75)(0.88)(0.0001)(0.98)(0.99) & \qquad [L,A,\neg F] \\
&= + (0.75)(0.001)(0.01)(0.98)(0.01) & \qquad [L,\neg A,F] \\
&= + (0.75)(0.001)(0.9999)(0.98)(0.99) & \qquad [L,\neg A,\neg F] \\
&= + (0.01)(0.12)(0.99)(0.98)(0.01) & \qquad [\neg L,A,F] \\
&= + (0.01)(0.12)(0.0001)(0.98)(0.99) & \qquad [\neg L,A,\neg F] \\
&= + (0.01)(0.999)(0.01)(0.98)(0.01) & \qquad [\neg L,\neg A,F] \\
&= + (0.01)(0.999)(0.9999)(0.98)(0.99) & \qquad [\neg L,\neg A,\neg F] \\
& \\
&= 0.01690. \\
& \\
\therefore\quad P(T\mid R) &= \dfrac{0.011227}{0.011227+0.01690} = 0.399
\end{align}

$\\$

Just for clarity, for example, the fourth term in the first numeric calculation: $$(0.75)(0.001)(0.15)(0.02)(0.99) \qquad [L,\neg A,\neg F]$$ equates to $$P(R\mid L)\;P(L\mid\neg A)\;P(\neg A\mid T,\neg F)\;P(T)\;P(\neg F).$$

Comment: Thankyou for the explanation. I do not understand why P(R) is written as P(R,T)+ P(R,not T)

Comment: @sam_rox That's just normal probability theory - not particular to Bayesian networks. From one of the axioms of probability, if sets $S,T$ are disjoint then $P(S)+P(T)=P(S\cup T)$.
For us, sets $R\cap T$ and $R\cap\neg T$ are disjoint so $P(R\cap T)+P(R\cap\neg T)=P((R\cap T)\cup(R\cap\neg T)) = P(R)$ since $\{T,\neg T\}$ is a partition of the sample space.